# How to keep a child selection after collapse the expandable list view

Tags: android, android-activity, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

How to keep a child selection after collapse the expandable list view. When the user selects one child in expandable list view after it collapse it will not shown ..

Comment: I am using Expandable list view for listing the question and answer , in first group when i expand show no of child , if i will select any from child in case i will expand second all selected child items set a un select.

Answer (score 1):

Implement onChild click listenr in your fragment/Activity

set the listener like below

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);
```

Code snippet:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        YourView yourView  = (YourView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_id);
        YourDataItem item = (YourDataItem) yourView.getTag();

        item.isSelected = !yourView.isChecked();

        yourView.setChecked(item.isSelected);

    }
```

Don't forget to setTag() in your  adapter

Comment: Can u explain briefly... i cant understand @Ram

Comment: Can you share your  adapter and fragment/activity code?   so that i can explain more clearly...!!

Comment: bro i am using fragment and sets Asyc task to receive datas from server ,.. it have list of question and answer each question has no of answer. . question has parent when it click , child list as a answer of that question

Comment: Ya i clearly wrote in above snippet.. what you dint get there...??
above code "YourDataItem" means  Number of answer

Comment: If you need clear explanation then at least provide, a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111728/discussion-between-vigneshwaran-t-and-ram).

Comment: can u come to chat?@Ram